# looping within a variable in panel data using loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have a panel data like `id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2), intm <- c(1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)`. The data frame is like
`dta <- data.frame(cbind(id,intm))` which gives:

```r
   id intm
1   1    1
2   1    1
3   1    0
4   1    0
5   1    1
6   1    0
7   1    0
8   2    0
9   2    0
10  2    0
11  2    1
12  2    1
```

I would like to replace the subsequent values of "intm" variable by the first value within the ID variable. That is for ID=1, the first value is 1, so the intm should have all values as 1 and for ID=2, intm should have all values as 0. The data should be like

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),intm <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0) with data frame

dta <- data.frame(cbind(id,intm))
```

How can I do this in R by looping or any other means? I have a big data set.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

```
new_column <- c(); i <- 1; # new column to be created

# loop
for (j in unique(dta$id)){ # let's separate the unique values of ID
  index <- which(dta$id==j) # which row index satisfy id==1, or id==2, ...?
  value <- dta$intm[index[1]] # which value of intm corresponds to the first value of the index?
  new_column[i:tail(index,n = 1)] <- rep(value,nrow(dta[id==j,])) # repeat this value the number of rows times which contains the ID
  i <- tail(index,n = 1)+1 # the new_column component must start with its last value + 1
}

dta <- cbind(dta,new_column)
```

Alternatively, you can use the `subset()` function, i.e

```
rep(value,nrow(subset(dta,dta$id==j)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` to do this.

There are other fancier ways to do this but I think `dplyr` is more graceful.

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)

intm <- c(1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)

df = data.frame(id, intm)

library(dplyr)

df2 = df %>% group_by(id) %>% do({
  .$intm = .$intm[1, drop = TRUE]
  .
})
```

You can also try `data.table` library which shall be faster.

BTW: you do not need `cbind` to make a `data.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `ave` + `head`

```r
dta$intm <- with(dta, ave(intm, id, FUN=function(x) head(x, 1)))
```